# tensorflow - linear regression does not give intended computational graph

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to train a very simple linear regression with tensorflow but the loss doesn't decrease and the tensorboard also doesn't look right

```
### Generate data
w_true = np.array([1.0,2.0])
b_true = 0.5

x_train = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean=[0,0], cov=[[1,0],[0,1]], size=100)
x_test = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean=[0,0], cov=[[3,0],[0,3]], size=100)
y_train = np.dot(x_train,w_true) + b_true
y_test = np.dot(x_test,w_true) + b_true

### Placeholders for data input
x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None,2], name="x")
y = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None], name="labels")

### Trainable parameters
w = tf.Variable(initial_value=np.random.multivariate_normal([0,0],[[1,0],[0,1]]), dtype=tf.float32,
               name="W")
b = tf.Variable(initial_value=np.random.normal(1), dtype=tf.float32,name="B")

### Computational graph
y_pred = tf.tensordot(x,w,1)+b
tf.summary.histogram("weights",w)
tf.summary.histogram("bias",b)
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.squared_difference(y,y_pred), name="loss")
tf.summary.scalar("loss", loss)
with tf.name_scope("train"):
    train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.00001).minimize(loss)

### Training
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

# For TensorBoard
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter("path_to_some_folder")
writer.add_graph(sess.graph)

for t in range(1000): 
    x_batch = x_train[np.random.choice(100, 20)]
    y_batch = y_train[np.random.choice(100, 20)]
    sess.run(train_step, {x:x_batch,y:y_batch})

print(sess.run(loss, {x:x_train,y:y_train}))
print(sess.run(loss, {x:x_test,y:y_test}))
```

I have tried different step sizes but the error always stays above 400 on the training and 1000 on the test set. I have tested that `tf.tensordot()` behaves like I expect. I you would like to see the tensorboard just replace the `path_to_some_folder` and after training run `tensorboard --logdir path_to_some_folder`

Thanks very much for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is because of the following two lines,

```
x_batch = x_train[np.random.choice(100, 20)]
y_batch = y_train[np.random.choice(100, 20)]
```

In each iteration, **np.random.choice(100, 20)** returns two different index lists for **x_batch** and **y_batch**. Therefore, your **x_batch** and **y_batch** will never match. Instead, replace that part with the following code.

```
BATCH_SIZE= 10
N_COUNT = len(x_train)

for t in range(1000):
    for start, end in zip(range(0, N_COUNT, BATCH_SIZE),
                          range(BATCH_SIZE, N_COUNT + 1,BATCH_SIZE)):
        x_batch = x_train[start:end]
        y_batch = y_train[start:end]
        sess.run(train_step, {x:x_batch,y:y_batch})
```

Hope this helps.